# How to predict using LinearRegressor in TensorFlow (without being forced to enter the solution)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm trying to learn some TensorFlow (Python) basics from Google's Crash Course online. However, I'm finding the explanations a little light and am confused how to use this beyond the examples / tasks they set.

For example, there is a basic task to predict housing prices in California using Linear Regression with Gradient Descent (see: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/validation.ipynb)

The tasks are all about training and then testing a model using an existing dataset. This works well, but I'm struggling to use the code to predict house prices for arbitrary input values (i.e. not from the test/training set).

The problem arises because the input function to the LinearRegressor requires you to enter the target values, which of course are unknown if you want to make predictions:

e.g.

```
predict_test_input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(
  test_examples, 
  test_targets["median_house_value"], 
  num_epochs=1, 
  shuffle=False)
```

where the my_input_func is defined within the Crash Course notebook (see link above).

If anyone is familiar with TensorFlow / the Google ML Crash Course, could you perhaps please explain what should be entered as a target value, when the point of using a trained model is to find unknown values?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: No target value, pass without it

Comment: Thanks for the comment, although from the way Google have defined the my_input_ft function, the targets is a required argument. I find their routine quite unclear here.